# Launch second activity from Fragment A using parent actiivity of Fragment A

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am standing before an interesting question. Is there a way (library, code, some hack) to solve my question ? Situation is like this:

We have Activity A with it's listViewFragment A.
When I click on item of that listView I need to launch Activity B. I do this by calling:

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

But that may lead to memory leaks or sometimes the getActivity() returns null because fragment is not attached to it's activity.

I imagine making some interface and calling it from there but I don't really know how to implement this idea.

Comment: Directly use your parent activity name instant of getActivity() and call startActivity(intent);  it may be work

Comment: I wanted something where I don't have to call startActivity from fragment

Comment: Sorry dear but as per my knowledge its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it simply works by calling startActivity from inside that fragment without calling parent activity.
Here is my solution:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list1);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Img records = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OrderActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Name", records.getName());
                intent.putExtra("Phone", records.getPhone());
                intent.putExtra("ID", records.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

before, I was calling it from inside adapter of that listView so I had to use getActivity. Now I don't have to.